# Parse text to show 3D triangles

Tags: matlab, geometry, octave, mesh

(Using Octacve) I have a text file with triangle vertices defined in this way:

```
((x11, y11, z11), (x12, y12, z12), (x13, y13, z13))((x21, y21, z21), (x22, y22, z22), (x23, y23, z23))...((xn1, yn1, zn1), (xn2, yn2, zn2), (xn3, yn3, zn3))
```

This is a list of triangles in 3D space, with every triangle defined as `((xn1, yn1, zn1)(xn2, yn2, zn2)(xn3, yn3, zn3))`.

How can I import this file in Octave in order to see the generated mesh? I know I can use `trimesh`, but I'm not be able to parse this file in order to retrieve point coordinates.

EDIT: This is a real file with some triangle:

```
((-0.780869, -1.56174, 4.68521), (-0.776988, -1.08169, 4.81936), (-0.776988, -2.02627, 4.5045))((-0.776988, -1.08169, 4.81936), (-0.765386, -0.590883, 4.90561), (-0.776988, -2.02627, 4.5045))((-0.776988, -2.02627, 4.5045), (-0.765386, -0.590883, 4.90561), (-0.765386, -2.47066, 4.27902))((-0.765386, -0.590883, 4.90561), (-0.746177, -0.0942074, 4.94311), (-0.765386, -2.47066, 4.27902))((-0.765386, -2.47066, 4.27902), (-0.746177, -0.0942074, 4.94311), (-0.746177, -2.8905, 4.01101))((-0.746177, -0.0942074, 4.94311), (-0.719552, 0.403404, 4.93148), (-0.746177, -2.8905, 4.01101))((-0.746177, -2.8905, 4.01101), (-0.719552, 0.403404, 4.93148), (-0.719552, -3.28161, 3.70314))((-0.719552, 0.403404, 4.93148), (-0.685776, 0.897006, 4.87084), (-0.719552, -3.28161, 3.70314))((-0.719552, -3.28161, 3.70314), (-0.685776, 0.897006, 4.87084), (-0.685776, -3.64011, 3.35847))((-0.685776, 0.897006, 4.87084), (-0.645184, 1.38169, 4.76179), (-0.685776, -3.64011, 3.35847))((-0.685776, -3.64011, 3.35847), (-0.645184, 1.38169, 4.76179), (-0.645184, -3.96243, 2.98042))((-0.645184, 1.38169, 4.76179), (-0.59818, 1.85265, 4.60542), (-0.645184, -3.96243, 2.98042))((-0.645184, -3.96243, 2.98042), (-0.59818, 1.85265, 4.60542), (-0.59818, -4.24537, 2.57274))((-0.59818, 1.85265, 4.60542), (-0.545231, 2.30519, 4.40327), (-0.59818, -4.24537, 2.57274))((-0.59818, -4.24537, 2.57274), (-0.545231, 2.30519, 4.40327), (-0.545231, -4.48612, 2.1395))((-0.545231, 2.30519, 4.40327), (-0.486864, 2.73482, 4.15737), (-0.545231, -4.48612, 2.1395))((-0.545231, -4.48612, 2.1395), (-0.486864, 2.73482, 4.15737), (-0.486864, -4.68228, 1.685))((-0.486864, 2.73482, 4.15737), (-0.423657, 3.13728, 3.87014), (-0.486864, -4.68228, 1.685))((-0.486864, -4.68228, 1.685), (-0.423657, 3.13728, 3.87014), (-0.423657, -4.83191, 1.21375))((-0.423657, 3.13728, 3.87014), (-0.356241, 3.50855, 3.54445), (-0.423657, -4.83191, 1.21375))((-0.423657, -4.83191, 1.21375), (-0.356241, 3.50855, 3.54445), (-0.356241, -4.93351, 0.730433))((-0.356241, 3.50855, 3.54445), (-0.285283, 3.84496, 3.18354), (-0.356241, -4.93351, 0.730433))((-0.356241, -4.93351, 0.730433), (-0.285283, 3.84496, 3.18354), (-0.285283, -4.98609, 0.23986))((-0.285283, 3.84496, 3.18354), (-0.211491, 4.14315, 2.79099), (-0.285283, -4.98609, 0.23986))((-0.285283, -4.98609, 0.23986), (-0.211491, 4.14315, 2.79099), (-0.211491, -4.98911, -0.253097))((-0.211491, 4.14315, 2.79099), (-0.135596, 4.40016, 2.3707), (-0.211491, -4.98911, -0.253097))((-0.211491, -4.98911, -0.253097), (-0.135596, 4.40016, 2.3707), (-0.135596, -4.94255, -0.743539))((-0.135596, 4.40016, 2.3707), (-0.0583544, 4.61344, 1.92684), (-0.135596, -4.94255, -0.743539))((-0.135596, -4.94255, -0.743539), (-0.0583544, 4.61344, 1.92684), (-0.0583544, -4.84686, -1.22659))
```

Comment: Could you add to your post (for testing purposes) some real data from the file?

Comment: I've added some real data (even if probably they are casual triangles. Infact I need to test if these triangles create some real object).

Comment: The generic structure and the example you gave have not the same format.  In your generic structure the vertices are not separated by commas, while in the example they are. Which one is the correct format of the file?

Comment: It way my mistake, sorry. I'll correct the structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(This was tested with MATLAB, but should work fine in Octave too)

To parse the file you may use the following function:

```
function A = fparse_triangle(fname)
        f = fopen(fname, 'r');
        A = reshape(fscanf(f, '((%f, %f, %f)(%f, %f, %f)(%f, %f, %f))'),3,3,[]);
        fclose(f);
end
```

The result will be a 3×3×*n* matrix, on first index having coordinates of vertices (*X*, *Y*, *Z*), on second index having vertices of a triangle (1st, 2nd, 3rd), and on third index having triangles.

**Later edit**

This alternative will take in account vertices that are separated by commas, as in the recently added example:

```
function A = fparse_triangle_alt(fname)
        f = fopen(fname, 'r');
        A = reshape(fscanf(f, '((%f, %f, %f), (%f, %f, %f), (%f, %f, %f))'),3,3,[]);
        fclose(f);
end
```

**NB**

Mind that from this to a `trimesh` call there's a bit more processing involved. Let me know if you'd need help with that.

Comment: Thanks, but I obtain the following error: `error: reshape: SIZE is not divisible by the product of known dimensions (= 9)`

Comment: @Jepessen Is the structure of the entire file the one you described, or only part of it? If it's the structure of the entire file, are you sure that is the correct one (up to spaces, newlines, tabs etc.)? If not, could you give us a sample of the file, exactly as it is?

Comment: There's a sample file in the header. It's as is, without spaces or newlines.

Comment: @Jepessen Please check my post, I presented an alternative that takes in the account the changes from the original generic structure that you proposed. It worked for me using the file content that you poasted, in MATLAB. Hope is okay in Octave too.